# Binary Tree printing out all zero's

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

When I print out the elements of this Binary Tree using my inOrder method, it prints: 0 0 0 0 0 0

Here is my Code:

```
public class BST {

 class Node {

  int data;
  Node left;
  Node right;

  public Node(int data) {
   data = data;
   left = null;
   right = null;
 }

public Node root;

/**
* Method to insert a new node in order
* in our binary search tree
*/
 public void insert(int data) {
  root = insert(root, data);
 }

public Node insert(Node node, int data){

if(node==null){
  node = new Node(data);
}else if (data < node.data){
  node.left = insert(node.left, data);
}else{
  node.right = insert(node.right, data);
}
return node;
}

 /** 
   Prints the node values in the "inorder" order.  
 */ 
   public void inOrder() { 
   inOrder(root); 
 }

  private void inOrder(Node node) { 
   if (node == null) 
  return;

  inOrder(node.left()); 
  System.out.print(node.data + " "); 
  inOrder(node.right); 
  } 
 }
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  BST tree = new BST();

  tree.insert(6);
  tree.insert(4);
  tree.insert(8);
  tree.insert(2);
  tree.insert(1);
  tree.insert(5);

  tree.inOrder();

 }
}
```

I have a feeling that it is something wrong in my insert method, I just can't figure out what. Any help in the right direction would be great, and sorry for being a noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Node` your constructor is setting the constructor argument to itself instead of initializing the class variable.

Use the keyword `this` in your ctor to distinguish from constructor arguments and class variable.

Example:

```
public class Pair 
{

  private int left;
  private int right;

  public Pair(int left, int right) {
    // the following 2 lines don't do anything
    // it set's the argument "left = left" which is silly...

    left = left;
    right = right;

    // with the `this` keyword we can correctly initialize our class properties
    // and avoid name collision

    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

}
```

Comment: @CodyReandeau glad to hear it :)